# How to protect keystore password in react native?

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, react-redux, keystore, android-keystore

can anyone help me with storing the keystone password in react native. How can I be sure that  its safe? how to protect it from reverse engineering or is it safe?

Answer (score 0):

You can store the password in a signing properties file which is not committed to your git repo. Then you can read the password from the file as below in `android/app/build.gradle`

```
// Load keystore
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file("signing.properties");
def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))

signingConfigs {
    release {
      storeFile file(keystoreProperties['storeFile'])
      storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
      keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
      keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
    }
    ...
```

signing.properties example

```
storeFile=/home/userName/Workspace/repoName/android/keystores/qa.keystore
storePassword=-----------------------
keyPassword=-----------------------
keyAlias=-----------------------
```

I place my signing.properties file in android folder within my react-native repo

add the following line to your .gitignore

```
android/signing.properties
```

Comment: This did not work for me..can you add more details to your answer?

Comment: What errors or issues did you face while trying this method ?
Also note that this is the method we use but there may be others ways to go about protecting your signing key. I think there is also a way to use keychain on mac to store and read your keystore passwords